# Something is creating inodes on my VPS Linux Server

Tags: linux, command-line

Please help, my server keeps exceeding the limit of iNodes (750,000). I'm not sure how these are being created. I do have multiple development sites on the server but it had never been a problem before.

What linux commands can I use to troubleshoot this?

df -i returns:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs       750000 749793     207  100% /
none           1048576    154 1048422    1% /dev
```

Comment: `/dev/vzfs`: It seems your VPS is OpenVZ-based. What hosting provider and plan are you using, and how much are you paying?

Comment: @DragonLord VPS, 1and, 'XXL Package', $30/month.  Please share any hosting suggestions and advice.

Comment: That's a pretty big VPS for the money--4 GB RAM burstable to 8 GB plus Plesk. I'm surprised they gave you only 750k inodes for a *200 GB* disk. Maybe you can talk to 1&1 support about the low inode limit? (I personally use [Linode](https://www.linode.com/) 2GB, which provides 48 GB SSD disk space, and I have more than 1.4M inodes available on the 12 GB system partition.)

Comment: Further research finds that 1&1 likes to set inode limits very low. It seems they're attracting customers by offering lots of RAM and disk space for the money, belied by an unusually low inode limit intended to upsell expensive, high-margin dedicated servers. I find this to be a deceptive practice, so you might want to switch to another hosting provider. There are lots of choices out there; do your research to make sure the hosting provider and plan you select will meet your needs. The two most consistently recommended hosting providers for developers these days are Linode and DigitalOcean.

Comment: @DragonLord Thank you VERY much for the great advice.  I will most definitely be switching hosts this week.  I will most likely be using one of your recommendations (if not than ASmallOrange).

Answer (score 0):

**List number of inodes in each folder:**

```
find . -type d | while read line ; do echo "$( find "$line" -maxdepth 1 | wc -l) $line" ; done | sort -rn | head
```

**List Empty Folders In Current Directory**

```
find / -type d -empty -depth
```

**List files by size:**

```
du -h --max-depth=1
```

**List files/folders by number of iNodes:**

find . -xdev -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

**List folders by number of iNodes:**

find . -xdev -type d | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

Comment: So, just out of curiosity: Did you find the actual culprit?

Comment: @DanielB
my .npm cache happened to be epically huge. This didn't actually solve the problem but allowed me to clear enough space to get some breathing room, back some stuff up, and re-image from an older state.